# How to store/save Ids and Passwords in webview?

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView app which opens up my Blog,
My blog has options to share posts via F.B, Twitter etc..
My problem is, Everytime a user wishes to share a post, he should Login everytime!
What should I do so that the Webview saves the id/pass so that the User doesn't need to Login each time...

Comment: you need to use CookieManager.

Comment: @ridoy can u explain with the full Code... m new to it :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to save cookies in order to save username password in web-view . 
But its deprecated in API 18. although you can use java script interfaces to save username passwords.

Comment: Nobody will provide you complete code here. you need to google how to use cookies in android.